# Cannot connect database as sys as sysdba using sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, listener

I am new to oracle server 18c (currently taking online course). My problem is sql*plus where I tried to use sqlplus then sys as sysdba (it did not work) and the error appeared below. 
[image]

However, if I use sqlplus / as sysdba (it worked, and I don't know why)
[image]

I have tried this command: lsnrctl start, but again not working. In addition, I have checked my listener.ora and tnsnames.oraca
[image]
[image]

I have attached my environment set up in .bash_profile
[image]

Please help me this. Thank you

Comment: Let me guess. The password you entered contains the `@` character.

Comment: yes, it was contained @ in the password

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the password contains special characters such as `@`, enter the password between double quotes:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Nov 11 15:41:40 2019
Version 19.5.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.5.0.0.0

SQL> connect sys/a@abcd as sysdba
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
SQL> connect sys/"a@abcd" as sysdba
Connected.
SQL>
```

Comment: A bit of explanation.  In your failed attempt, you supplied a pswd that contained a '@' which gets interpreted as a delimiter of the connection string, so the password gets shorted, and an invalid connect string is passed.  In the successful attempt '/ as sysdba', no username/password was needed because the stand-alone '/' indicates to use OS authentication - trust the OS to have authenticated a user that is a member of the OS 'dba' group.

Comment: I wanted to thank you, after countless hours of searching, this worked for me:
connect sys/"a@abcd" as sysdba
Even when I used the Oracle appliance, with the default password of "oracle"
This did not make any sense, but I am happy I am in now.